# abort: error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known error

Tags: core-plot

can anyone help ??
i am getting this error while connecting..

```
abort: error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

please help me out.

Actually I want to get the source of coreplot from a repository I am executing this command in the terminal

```
"hg clone core-plot.googlecode.com/hg core-plot "
```

and i get the error ...

```
"abort: error: nodename nor servname provided or not known,"
```

Can any1 help me?

Comment: Please provide more details: connecting to what?

Comment: What are you trying to connect to? Using what utility/library/language/protocol? We're not telepaths.

Answer (score 8):

Check your proxy settings. I've had issues with having my http_proxy/https_proxy environment variables set to a corporate setting while off-corp-LAN and have seen similar responses.

Comment: Thanks. That was precisely my problem.

Comment: I just had a similar issue - at some point I had lost my wifi connection. It's hard to pull when you don't have an internet connection :/

Answer (score 2):

This is often intermittent and DNS related.  Check your network connectivity and/or proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

This message indicates a general networking issue. See if you can ping the hostname in question. If you can't reach it you may need to manually update your "hosts" file or perform other related DNS voodoo until the ping returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`hg clone https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/ core-plot`

Note that the `https://` is required.

Comment: Hi Eric ,I tried that but still I am getting the same error.Do I have to change any settings before executing the command?...

Answer (score 0):

While it's not 100% related (as I think the original issue was a missing "https://") I wanted to post my problem for SO google-juice.

I was having the same error message when cloning from bitbucket.org; I had missed adding @ to the url:

```
hg clone https://<my_username>@bitbucket.org/<someone>/<project>/
```

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates a general networking issue. See your network with connected with correct connection or any other connection.

Example: In my office if i connect with Lan only then the mercurial will work(Like clone or update or pull). But i tried via guest connection(Wifi). Once i change this now its working.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it on mac:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```